# PHP SQL - Get Total for specific IDs w/ Multiple IDs

Tags: mysql

I'm mainly curious.

I'm building a custom web app for businesses to help keep track of jobs (among many other things) and one feature they are looking for is being able to see how many jobs a person is performing and what status those jobs are in. They are looking for totals for each staff member for each job status (e.g. someone can have 20 jobs, 5 in a 'New' status, 6 'In Progress', etc). Is there a way to collect this information using a SQL query? The jobs table has the status ID numbers under a "job_status" column and the same table has each staff member's ID numbers under a "job_tech" column.

I was thinking of just query each status and group by staff member name (with the help of an INNER JOIN) and append to a PHP multi-dimensional array so I can later add that data in to a table but I felt this was clunky, at best.

I've tried something like this:

```
SELECT
        user_fullName,
        COUNT(job_id) as Total,
        COUNT(job_status = 12) AS Complete,
        COUNT(job_status = 1) AS Scheduled,
        COUNT(job_status = 3) AS 'In Progress',
        COUNT(job_status = 4) AS 'Quote Required'
FROM jobs
LEFT JOIN users ON jobs.job_tech = users.user_id
WHERE job_dateCompleted LIKE '2023%'
GROUP BY user_fullName
```

But this only returns the *total* of jobs for that staff member in each column defined. I'll be the first to admit that I am *not* a SQL guy of any kind. I'm lucky if running basic inserterting, selecting and updating queries doesn't cause problems.

Any ideas?

Comment: Usually this is done by summing up 1/0 values - `SUM(IF(job_status = 12, 1, 0)) as Complete`

Comment: count counts non-null values, so unless job_status is null, job_status = N comparison will return a true or false - both being non-null values.

Comment: The first one should be `COUNT(*)`; in the rest, change `COUNT` to `SUM`.

Comment: Thank you @RickJames ! That did the trick!!